# Connecting nested view to view model in Prism 4.0 and MEF

Tags: prism, mef

I am a newbie on MEF and trying to figure out how to structure my Prism 4.0 application to connect views to view models. My use case is that I have one user control nested inside another user control. I would like to connect the nested user control to its view model. I have tried to follow Prism 4.0 examples but not sure if I am using MEF best practices.

Here are some snippets from my application to demonstrate the issue. HomeView has a nested user control called HelloView. I need to connect HelloView to its view model called HelloViewModel. The code in its current state does not work. I think HelloView is not being constructed by MEF and hence HelloViewModel is not being connected.

```
***** HomeModule *****
[ModuleExport(typeof(HomeModule))]
public class HomeModule : IModule
{
    IRegionManager _regionManager;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public HomeModule(IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        _regionManager = regionManager;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        // Create the view
        IHomeView homeView = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IHomeView>();

        // Add it to the region
        IRegion region = _regionManager.Regions["MainRegion"];
        region.Add(homeView, "HomeView");
        region.Activate(homeView);
    }
}


****** IHomeView *****
public interface IHomeView
{
}


***** HomeView.xaml *****
<UserControl ...>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <view:HelloView x:Name="helloView"/>
    </Grid>

</UserControl>


***** HomeView.xaml.cs *****
[Export(typeof(IHomeView))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public partial class HomeView : UserControl, IHomeView
{
    public HomeView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}


***** IHelloView *****
public interface IHelloView
{
}


***** HelloView.xaml *****
<UserControl ...>
    <StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="10">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <TextBlock Text="Name" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBox Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10 0 0 0"
                     Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Button Content="Submit" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10 0 0 0"
                    Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" Margin="0 10 0 0" Foreground="Red" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>

***** HelloView.xaml.cs *****
[Export(typeof(IHelloView))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public partial class HelloView : UserControl, IHelloView
{
    public HelloView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [Import]
    public IHelloViewModel ViewModel
    {
        set { this.DataContext = value; }
    }
}


***** IHelloViewModel *****
public interface IHelloViewModel
{
}


***** HelloViewModel *****
[Export(typeof(IHelloViewModel))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class HelloViewModel : NotificationObject, IHelloViewModel
{
    public HelloViewModel()
    {
        this.SubmitCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(this.OnSubmit);
    }

    private void OnSubmit(object obj)
    {
        Message = "Hello " + Name;
    }

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _name)
            {
                _name = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _message;
    public string Message
    {
        get { return _message; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _message)
            {
                _message = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Message");
            }
        }
    }

    public ICommand SubmitCommand { get; private set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is OK, I only have 2 notes: 
First: If your catalog contains more than 1 type of IHelloViewModel (that is most likely because you have several views and viewmodels correspondingly) then you get a composition error because import returns more than one result.

```
[Import]public IHelloViewModel ViewModel
```

should be something like

```
[Import(typeof(HelloViewModel))] IHelloViewModel ViewModel
```

or you just make your property like:

```
   [Import]
public HelloViewModel ViewModel
```

Second:
 Do dont use `ServiceLocator` for the creation of your `HomeView`. `ServiceLocator` is intended to create the singleton instances and `EventAggregator` is the perfect candidate for that. Views should be not shared (and you correctly marked it as `[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]` - otherwise is you want to add your view to another region you get error.)
)

use

```
   [Import]
    public HomeView HomeView
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks grimcoder! Good tips.I think my original post did not make it clear that the code actually does NOT work - HelloView does not get connected to HelloViewModel. I am guessing that the construction of HelloView is not going through MEF. What's the best way to make this hookup?

Comment: From your code I cannot see why your ViewModel property is not getting picked up, your code is incomplete - IHelloViewModel is missing. 
Also, PRISM recommends making View/ViewModel association inside the Module Initialise() method.

Comment: I have added the IHelloViewModel code to my original post - its just an empty interface. I was hoping that MEF would allow connecting views to view models more automatically (instead of making them manually in the module initialize method).

Comment: @Naresh: the only way to do that with MEF would be to Import your IHelloViewModel in the constructor of your view and assign that to the view's datacontext.  This will couple your viewmodel and your view, but that's generally the case anyway.